# Upon creating a Maintenace Plan in SSMS 17.6, SSMS automatially restarts upon attempting to schedule the task to run

Tags: scheduled-tasks, ssms, maintenance-plan

The architecture is Server 2016 with SQL 2016 Standard.  SSMS has been set to run as administrator.  SSMS 17.6 has been installed and re-installed.  All Microsoft updates have been installed to the serer and the application.

Creating a Maintenance Plan and manually executing does not cause an issue.

Answer (score 1):

today i ran into exact same issue at a system from my customers. It looks like a version specific issue.

**Errors i got:**

- .NET Runtime Event ID 1026
- Application Error ID 1000
- Windows Error Reporting Event 1001

  - CLR20r3
  - System.NullReferenceException

**Environment:**

- New Windows Server 2016 with all updates,
- latest SQL Server 2016 Standard available,
- SQL Server Management Studio 17.6.

I'm also not able to edit the scheduler for the maintenance sub-plans. While clicking on the icon to modify the scheduler, the application crashes and restarts automaticly.

Uninstalling all SSMS 17-Versions and reinstalling a previous version solved the issue for me. I have tested it with version 17.4 and 17.5 without problems. As long 17.6 was installed, also 17.4 shows the same effect, so uninstalling 17.6 seams to be mandatory in this case.

best regards,

Sven

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known issue with SSMS 17.6, the suggested workaround is to uninstall 17.6 and reinstall 17.5 (or earlier) until the fix can be released in the next version of SSMS.

Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

*There is a known issue where SSMS 17.6 becomes unstable and crashes when using Maintenance Plans. If you use Maintenance Plans, do not install SSMS 17.6. Downgrade to SSMS 17.5 if you already installed 17.6 and this issue is affecting you.*

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018-08-11, SSMS 17.8.1 is available for download. The scheduler button under each subplan section for each Maintenance plan does NOT crash or restart the studio.